# PHP Crawler takes all the Memory from server

Tags: php, web-crawler

I wrote a really simple PHP crawler, but I have problem with the memory loss. The code is:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';

$homepage = 'https://example.com';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `crawled_urls`";
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$already_crawled = [];
$crawling = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
  $already_crawled[] = $row['crawled_url'];
  $crawling[] = $row['crawled_url'];
}

function follow_links($url){
  global $already_crawled;
  global $crawling;
  global $dbc;

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

  $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

  foreach ($linklist as $link) {
    $l = $link->getAttribute("href");
    $full_link = 'https://example.com'.$l;

    if (!in_array($full_link, $already_crawled)) {

      // TODO: Fetch data from the crawled url and store it in the DB. Check if it was already stored.

      $query = 'INSERT INTO `crawled_urls`(`id`, `crawled_url`) VALUES (NULL,\'' . $full_link . '\')';
      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

      echo $full_link.PHP_EOL;
    }
  }

  array_shift($crawling);

  foreach ($crawling as $link) {
    follow_links($link);
  }
}

follow_links($homepage);
```

Can you help me out and share with me a way to avoid this huge memory loss? When I start the process it is all working fine, but the memory is steadily rising up to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `unset` `$doc` when you no longer need it:

```
function follow_links($url){
  global $already_crawled;
  global $crawling;
  global $dbc;

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

  $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

  unset($doc);

  foreach ($linklist as $link) {
    $l = $link->getAttribute("href");
    $full_link = 'https://example.com'.$l;

    if (!in_array($full_link, $already_crawled)) {

      // TODO: Fetch data from the crawled url and store it in the DB. Check if it was already stored.

      $query = 'INSERT INTO `crawled_urls`(`id`, `crawled_url`) VALUES (NULL,\'' . $full_link . '\')';
      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

      echo $full_link.PHP_EOL;
    }
  }

  array_shift($crawling);

  foreach ($crawling as $link) {
    follow_links($link);
  }
}

follow_links($homepage);
```

Explanation: You are using recursion, that is, you are using a stack of functions basically. This means that if you have a stack of 20 elements, all the resources for all the functions in your stack will be allocated accordingly. The deeper this gets the more memory you use. `$doc` is the main problem, but you may want to look at the usage of your other variables and make sure nothing unneeded is allocated when you call the function again.

Comment: Sadly, the problem continues. It is taking more time now, but the memory keeps on rising. I think I have to scrap everything and search for a ready to use option.. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab the fact that now the problem is slower to appear clearly means that we have made a large improvement. You could just make sure that all the variables in use will be freed, or you can use a stack on your own.

Comment: Your idea on the level of the algorithm is correct, you face technical difficulties due to recursion. With recursion you are implicitly using a stack of functions. Since you have a problem of memory leak, you could get rid of the recursive function call and convert your code to an iterative code, explicitly using a stack: http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will explore it and will make changes to avoid recursion. I appreciate your answers!!

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab you are welcome. I think my answer answers the question, as it pointed out the lack of freeing resources in your recursive function. You might consider accepting it as the correct answer, however, you do not really need to implement the stack in PHP yourself, PHP has already implemented it, you will just need to use it.

Comment: So if I have to explain the memory leak, it is happening due to the recursion. Meaning that, after every new link, the array with stored links is getting larger and it is taking more memory for the script to go trough the full list and search if the link exists and if not, to store it. Am I getting this part right?

Comment: What do you mean by:

"however, you do not really need to implement the stack in PHP yourself, PHP has already implemented it, you will just need to use it" 

How can I use it and stop the memory leak?

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab That's one of the causes of recursion indeed. Another reason is any other variable existing in the function. If you have a function f and it's calling itself, when the second one is executed, you will have twice as many resources allocated as local variables. And then the function is called again.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab this is a PHP implementation for the Stack: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ds-stack.php

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab You will need to implement a cycle which always pops the top of a stack which contains links and does the crawling for it and pushes any new links to the stack while doing so.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab also, you have a prepared statement where you insert a single record. It would make much more sense to group maybe 100 records to insert and execute the insert in batches. It would quick up the code significantly.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement the logic and watch out for variables that must be "spared"

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab Finally, if you have an ever growing set which challenges your memory, then storing the data into a table might make sense.

Comment: Did not think of this! Thank you again :)

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab if you convert your algorithm from recursive to iterative, then memory leak will be much lesser of a concern. There are high chances that you will have no leak whatsoever, but even if you do, it will be much easier to solve, as your variables will be variables inside a cycle instead of compartmentalized into separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `unset` the `$doc` variable before calling the function:

```
function follow_links($url){
  global $already_crawled;
  global $crawling;
  global $dbc;

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

  $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

  foreach ($linklist as $link) {
    $l = $link->getAttribute("href");
    $full_link = 'https://example.com'.$l;

    if (!in_array($full_link, $already_crawled)) {

      // TODO: Fetch data from the crawled url and store it in the DB. Check if it was already stored.

      $query = 'INSERT INTO `crawled_urls`(`id`, `crawled_url`) VALUES (NULL,\'' . $full_link . '\')';
      $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

      echo $full_link.PHP_EOL;
    }
  }

  array_shift($crawling);
  unset($doc);

  foreach ($crawling as $link) {
    follow_links($link);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your code is that you are using recursion. That way, you are keeping old pages in memory, although you don't need them any more.

Try removing that recursion. It should be relatively easy, since you are already using lists to store your links. I would prefer to use one list and represent URLs as objects, however.

Some other things:

- Looks like you have a SQL injection vulnerability, so learn to use prepared statements correctly
- Avoid using global variables (you can make your function return a list of links)
- If you plan to use this code on other people's websites ensure you obey `robots.txt`, limit your crawl rate and make sure you don't crawl pages multiple times

If you want to use this code for something other than education, I suggest you use a library. This will be easier than creating a crawler from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome advises!! Can you pint me to a library that is good enough to be used? One more time thank you! :)

Comment: I would, but unfortunately I can't remember having used one. I'm sure you will find one using your favorite search engine ;) Good luck!